Set the line spacing between 2 lines iTextSharp
I am using iTextSharp to generate pdf.  I have a table and need to add text in the table cell. I used Chunks & paragraph to add text in table. For new line I use \n in chunks. But the line spacing between 2 lines is very narrow and I wan to increase the line spacing 2 lines. If give give \n 2 times that will increase the size.   How can I set line spacing?  I tried SetLeading but it's not working.
     PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

 Chunk pc1 = new Chunk(model.firstName +" "+model.lastName+" ("+gender+")"+ " / "+model.age +" Y\n", AptosBold);          
 Chunk pc2 = new Chunk("Mobile : ", AptosBold);
 Chunk pc3 = new Chunk(model.mobilephone+"\n", Aptos);
 Chunk pc4 = new Chunk("Weight : ", AptosBold);
 Chunk pc5 = new Chunk(model.patient_weight + " kg ", Aptos);
 Chunk pc6 = new Chunk("Height : ", AptosBold);
 Chunk pc7 = new Chunk(model.height + " cm ", Aptos);
 Chunk pc8 = new Chunk("BP : ", AptosBold);
 Chunk pc9 = new Chunk(model.bp_low+" / "+model.bp_high +"\n", Aptos);

 Phrase p = new Phrase();
 p.Add(pc1); p.Add(pc2); p.Add(pc3); p.Add(pc4); p.Add(pc5); p.Add(pc6); p.Add(pc7); p.Add(pc8); p.Add(pc9);
 Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
 paragraph.SetLeading(0, 1.9f);
 paragraph.Add(p);
          

 PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(paragraph);
 cell.Border = 0;
 cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
 cell.Padding = 0;
 cell.BorderColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
 table.AddCell(cell);

